# Populating textBoxes with

Tags: c#, linq

I'm designing a CheckOut page and I want to automatically load the signed in user's information with data from the database using linq. I'm using a method `FillPage` which I call in `PageLoad` and so far it looks like this:

```
void FillPage(int id)
{
    using (DatabaseContext db=new DatabaseContext()
    {

        var query = (from user in db.[tblUser]
                 where user.ID == id
                 select user
                ).First();

        if (query != null)
        {
            txtName.Text = query.Username;
            txtEmail.Text = query.Email;
            txtAddress.Text = query.PostalAddress;
            ddProvice.SelectedValue = query.Province;
            lblPassword.Text = query.Password;
            lblDate.Text = query.DateRegistered.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Why does nothing happen when I load the page?

Comment: What page are you loading? Is it a website? Local application? Are you sure FillPage() and PageLoad() are working currectly?

Comment: Your [MCVE] won't compile. Fix that first ...

Comment: @RikP  its a website.Im not sure whether FillPage() is woking since  not text is being displayed when page is loaded.

Comment: thnx @rere let me try that

Comment: Insert your pageload complete in your question

Answer (score 0):

You must insert more of your code .your problem is not clear

May be in your load event of your page you forget to add

```
 If (! IsPostback)
    {
    }
```

And may be you have reset your fields

```
  public void MyPage_load( object sender , EventArgs e)
{ 
    //Reset fields
}
```

This will fix your problem

```
public void MyPage_load( object sender , EventArgs e)
{ 
    If (! IsPostback)
    {
         //Reset fields
    }
 }
```